# CSS / JavaScript - content outside a element with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, absolute

I have a container div element that has `overflow:hidden` on it. Unfortunately this property is required on it because of the way the site is made.

Inside this div it's all the site content, including some tooltips. These tooltips are displayed with jQuery when you mouse over a link or something.

The problem is that some of these tooltips will display partially hidden because of the overflow thing above, because they are positioned outside the container div...

Is there any way to be able to show a specific element from inside this container, even if it's out of its boundaries? Maybe a javascript solution?

the html looks like this:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; position:relative;">

  the main content

  <div style="position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-50px;"> the tooltip thing </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">    
  <div style="overflow:hidden; position: relative; width: {any}; height: {any};">the main content<div>    
  <div style="position:absolute;left:-100px;top:-50px;"> the tooltip thing </div>    
</div>
```

just place your main content to another div inside the main div and give provided css to hide the content if overflowing...

Comment: Additionally, `margin:0px;padding:0px` on the containing div will ensure that there is no visible change from it being there

Comment: Just adding "overflow:none" & "position:relative" worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

CSS works like a box, and sometimes, you have elements "flowing out". Setting `overflow: hidden` on the main element hides contents that flow out of this box.

Consider the following:

**HTML**

`<div class="box">This box has a height and a width. This means that if there is too much content to be displayed within the assigned height, there will be an overflow situation. If overflow is set to hidden then any overflow will not be visible.</div>`

`<p>This content is outside of the box.</p>`

**CSS**

`.box {`
`border: 1px solid #333333;`
`width: 200px;`
`height: 100px;`
`overflow: hidden;`
}`

This outputs the following:
[image]

Note that the rest of the texts that overflow are hidden.

Answer (score -1):

if overflow:hidden is to contain floats, then there are other ways that would allow tooltips to not be cut off. look foe clearfix:after